# Are the public at large aware that Tony Stark created Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-age-of-ultron

So we as viewers and the Avengers as a whole of course know that Tony Stark created Ultron.  The question is, is the general public aware of this?

Comment: I haven't seen Civil War, but it seems that would be a significant source of the call to register powered folk.

Comment: I was just about to ask this same question.

Comment: @Matt I won't spoil it for you, but the audience sees another significant blunder that is the rallying point, although the piece of legislation is called the "Sokovia Accords"

Comment: Yeah, even <spoiler!> seemed upset with the Avengers as a whole rather than Stark in particular, which made me think it wasn't about Ultron's creation.  It makes no sense to me - apparently letting Ultron destroy the world or letting Hydra kill millions of people with a biological weapon would be *much* more sensible than trying to stop them and <gasp!> *endangering some bystanders*.  But who said politics makes sense?

Comment: @Matt: What does creating an artificial intelligence have to do with being super-powered? A scientist as intelligent as Stark but without the suits could have done the same thing, as long as he had access to the mind gem. Doctor Selvig had access to the scepter for quite some time and could have done it if he wasn't... busy doing something else at the time and actually cared about AI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There is no evidence that the public is aware.

Nothing in the films (*Age of Ultron* and *Civil War*) or in their scripts suggests that the general public knows anything about Tony Stark's direct involvement in the creation of Ultron.

In *Civil War*, the public seems to be concerned only with the *collateral damage* caused by the Avengers' missions.  Consistent with this, the Sokovia Accords seem to be focused squarely on limiting this kind of damage (particularly on foreign soil), by controlling when and where the Avengers are deployed.

If anything, Tony Stark seems as popular as ever, given Peter Parker and Aunt May's reaction to him.